# How to pop-up message on the exact card where it's clicked?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, popup

I'm trying to show some elements in a list of cards and when I click on a card, I need to show a pop-up message on that exact card. Right now it's showing up the top card. But I need to it to show up on the card I click.

Here's my html code for showing card elements and pop-up:

```
<a class="external" ng-repeat="card in cardData" ng-click="popUpFunction()">                             
  <div class="card">
      <img class="card-image" src="{{card.thumbNail_image}}" alt="">
      <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-infos">                              
          <h2 class="card-title">{{card.contentDescription}}</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

Here's the css code:

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  margin-left: 80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

And here's the js code:

```
$scope.popUpFunction = function () {
   var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
   popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I passed the index of the card as a parameter and checked it in `ng-if`

```
<a class="external" ng-repeat="card in cardData" ng-click="popUpFunction()">                             
  <div class="card">
      <img class="card-image" src="{{card.thumbNail_image}}" alt="">
      <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup" ng-if="popUpIndex==$index">A Simple Popup!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-infos">                              
          <h2 class="card-title">{{card.contentDescription}}</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

And here's the change in script file:

```
$scope.popUpIndex = 0;
$scope.modalFunction = function (ind) {
    console.log(ind);
    $scope.popUpIndex = ind;
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element clicked passing the event to the function. In the event object, you can extract the target property which is the element clicked. Here it is a quick demo to illustrate.

Also, it seems that you have your on click on a loop, I don't know angularJS but I think it would be something like this:

```
<div class="card" ng-click="popUpFunction($event)">       // notice the $event
```

instead of

```
<a class="external" ng-repeat="card in cardData" ng-click="popUpFunction()">
```

```js
function onClickShowMessage(event) {
  const card = event.target;
  const message = createMessageElement();
  card.appendChild(message);
}

function createMessageElement() {
  const message = document.createElement('p');
  message.innerHTML = 'This is some message';
  message.classList.add('message');
  return message;
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.message {
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<a class="card" onclick="onClickShowMessage(event)"></a>
<a class="card" onclick="onClickShowMessage(event)"></a>
<a class="card" onclick="onClickShowMessage(event)"></a>
```